# Remove line from top of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have searched this site and others but I cannot solve my issue with html or CSS. A line appears above my table [here](http://beavercanoeclub.org/welcome-test/).

Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" width="840" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><colgroup> <col style="width: 70%;" /> <col style="width: 30%;" /> </colgroup>
<tbody><tr><td>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: Calibri,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong><span style="font-size: 28px;">Learn to Paddle. Make Friends. Have Fun.</span></strong></span></h1>
</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, your `<td>`s have borders. I was able to remove them with CSS using the inspector. Just change it to `<td style="border: 0;">` (or make a class).